# Does spark keep all elements of an RDD[K,V] for a particular key in a single partition after "groupByKey" even if the data for a key is very huge?

Tags: apache-spark, rdd

Consider I have a PairedRDD of,say 10 partitions. But the keys are not evenly distributed, i.e, all the 9 partitions having data belongs to a single key say `a` and rest of the keys say `b,c` are there in last partition only.This is represented by the below figure:
[image]

Now if I do a `groupByKey` on this `rdd`, from my understanding all data for same key will eventually go to different partitions or no data for the same key will not be in multiple partitions. Please correct me if I am wrong.

If that is the case then there can be a chance that **the partition for key `a` can be of size that may not fit in a worker's RAM**. In that case what spark will do ? My assumption is like it will spill the data to worker's disk.
Is that correct?
Or how spark handle such situations

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Does spark keep all elements (...) for a particular key in a single partition after `groupByKey`

Yes, it does. This is a whole point of the shuffle.

> the partition for key a can be of size that may not fit in a worker's RAM. In that case what spark will do

Size of a particular partition is not the biggest issue here. Partitions are represented using lazy `Iterators` and can easily store data which exceeds amount of available memory. The main problem is non-lazy local data structure generated in the process of grouping.

All values for the particular key are stored in memory as a `CompactBuffer` so a single large group can result in OOM. Even if each record separately fits in memory you may still encounter serious GC issues.

In general:

- It is safe, although not optimal performance wise, to repartition data where amount of data assigned to a partition exceeds amount of available memory.
- It is not safe to use `PairRDDFunctions.groupByKey` in the same situation.

**Note**: You shouldn't extrapolate this to different implementations of `groupByKey` though. In particular both Spark `Dataset` and `PySpark` `RDD.groupByKey` use more sophisticated mechanisms.

Comment: I updated the answer. You may also check https://github.com/awesome-spark/spark-gotchas/blob/master/04_rdd_actions_and_transformations_by_example.md#be-smart-about-groupbykey (disclaimer: I'm co-author).

Comment: One more thing: first, whole data for a particular key will come to a single partition in single worker node, then as second step local grouping will happen to form RDD[k,Iterable(v)]. right? is there any chance to fail it in the first step due to insufficient local memory

Comment: Like I said - repartitioning is typically and `groupByKey` doesn't perform map side combine so it is unlikely to fail there, not that it makes any difference. Regarding links nothing more than source and what I've already shared.

Comment: Are you sure about this? cuz I see a comment in #PairRDDFunctions#groupbyKey:`@note As currently implemented, groupByKey must be able to hold all the key-value pairs for any
   key in memory. If a key has too many values, it can result in an OutOfMemoryError.`  (Spark 3.0 version)