# Does spark keep all data for a key in a single partition after partitioning by that key

Tags: apache-spark

This might be a duplicate of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39558547/does-spark-keep-all-elements-of-an-rddk-v-for-a-particular-key-in-a-single-par)

Since it was already answered, creating a new question for more visibility. If that is not the right way, I can move my question as a comment to the above question.

According to the answer, all data for a key resides in a single partition. But, this answer from spark mail group, says different. [link to spark dev group](http://apache-spark-developers-list.1001551.n3.nabble.com/Spark-SQL-Avoid-shuffles-when-data-is-already-partitioned-on-disk-td16064.html)

> It is not necessary if you are using bucketing available in Spark 2.0. For partitioning, it is still necessary because we do not assume each partition is small, and as a result there is no guarantee all the records for a partition end up in a single Spark task partition.

Can someone please confirm whether all data for a partition ends up in a single task partition or not. Any links to doc or source code would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

These two posts discuss different problems.

The developers list thread discuss the problem of reading data from partitioned data source, i.e. one written with `partitionBy`:

```
val df: DataFrame = ???
df.write.partitionBy("foo").saveAsTable("some_table")
```

When reading data like this a single on-disk "partition" can be loaded into multiple partitions so it cannot be used to optimize execution plan.

In contrast [Does spark keep all elements of an RDD[K,V] for a particular key in a single partition after "groupByKey" even if the data for a key is very huge?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39558547/6910411) discusses the problem of partitioning `PairRDDs` and it is not related to Spark SQL or data loading process. When you use:

```
val rdd: RDD[(T, U)] = ???
val partitioner: Partitioner = ???

rdd.partitionBy(partitioner)
```

all values for a particular key will be shuffled to a single partition.